# Load table using AJAX calls in Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have three view files in views folder  and i want to show category table and product table by click in link button using ajax call... 
`input.php` display both table data

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
         <h1>View Two Records By Click Event</h1>
        </div>

    <div id="show-catg">  
        <?php $this->load->view('show'); ?> 
    </div>  

    <div id="show-prd">  
         <?php $this->load->view('show_pro'); ?> 
    </div>
```

but i want to show this using click event.. like

```
<a href="" class="show_catg">Categories</a> 
<a href="" class="show_prd">Product</a>
$('.show_catg').click(function(){
  url:,
  data:,
});
$('.show_prd').click(function(){
  url:
  data:
});
```

this is may controller class function

```
  public function index(){  
    $data= $this->Model_data->getAll_categories();  
    $data1 = $this->Model_data->getAll_product();
    $Dataa = array('categories' => $data,"products"=>$data1);
    $this->load->view('input',$Dataa); 

  }
```

Model_data class

```
  function getAll_categories(){  
    $this->db->select('*');  
    $this->db->from('categories');  
    $this->db->limit(50);  
    $this->db->order_by('Catg_ID','ASC');  
    $query = $this->db->get();  

    return $query->result();  
  }  
public function getAll_product(){  
    $this->db->select('*');  
    $this->db->from('product');  
    $this->db->limit(50);  
    $this->db->order_by('Prod_ID','ASC');  
    $query = $this->db->get();  

    return $query->result();  
  }
```

Comment: okay.. but really need help.... :|

Answer (score 1):

First call `getAll_categories()` in a different method. like

In `Xyz.php` file (controller)

```
public function get_cat(){  
  $data = $this->Model_data->getAll_categories(); 
  $html  = ''; 
  foreach($data as $d){
    $html .= '<li>'.$d['cat_name'].'</li>';
  } 
 echo $html;
 }
```

jquery code

```
$('.show_catg').click(function(){
  url: site_url('xyz/get_cat'),
  type:'post',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function (response) {
      $('#suggestion').show().html(response);
   },
});
```

do in similar manner for `getAll_product()` method

Comment: sir i didn't get how to call may view data through ajax  and yes i already did that.... as i mentioned i created 3 view files in which 1 file fetch the record from the database but the thing is i'm not getting how can i call my view category file through ajax which is in a seperate file.... this is my category view

 <?php  foreach ($categories as $row){  

 
 echo "<tr class=\"record\">";  
    echo    "<td>$row->Catg_ID</td>";
 echo    "<td>$row->Catg_Name</td>";  

 echo  "</tr>";  
 }  
 ?>